# Find out specific Exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Apologies for the lack of information...

Is there a way to find out what is the specific Exception that is causing a call to throw the Exception?

Currently, I am catching all the Exceptions by doing **catch(Exception e)** but I know this is not good practices at all.

Is there a way to know from the Exception what is the specific one that caused the issue so I can be more granular?

Comment: e.GetType() tells you to exact type?

Comment: In addition to checking at runtime with GetType(), you can also catch the specific types of exceptions your code in the try will throw. You should be able to determine the types of exceptions thrown by the code via intellisense. It's been a little while since I've been in java, but I'm pretty sure you have to have the 'throws' keyword on a function to indicate the types of exceptions that will be thrown, and presumably your IDE has an autocomplete function which will fill out a catch case for each exception type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get more information for the particular exception using different methods on it. Here I'm using the `System.Diagnostics.Debug` class to print in Visual Studio's output console. In your catch block:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

try  
{
    // do stuff
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.GetType());  // Displays the type of exception
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message());  // Displays the exception message
}
```

You can see more here: [Exception methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) &
                       [Exception properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1 - Documentation

Read the documentation of the method you are calling, if it is a Framework Class type (like [SqlConnection.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx)) the thrown exceptions are *well* documented.

## Option 2 - Discover them at Run Time

If its a 3rd party library and documentation is limited then check the `Exception` at runtime using `exception.GetType()` and then add known exceptions you want to handle as `catch` blocks.

Personally I prefer to not add `catch` blocks at all where I am not sure if an Exception will materialize or not. If/When it does the debugger will break (if it is set to break) or you have a global catch all that logs and rethrows. Then you get the type and update your code accordingly. Where you add such a global Exception logger depends on the type of application you are developing. If you go the route of a global logger do take note that you 1) rethrow the Exception so the app breaks at runtime and *not* swallow it and 2) rethrow using `throw;` syntax (not `throw ex;`).

Answer (score 0):

You can catch different types of exceptions. With this solution you are able to handle the different types easily.

```
try
{
    //Try something
}
catch (StackOverflowException soe)
{
    //Handle StackOverFlowException
}
catch (FormatException fe)
{
    //Handle FormatException
}
//... Other exceptions
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it more specific for logging errors, try something like:

```
e.GetType()
```

Or, if you need some more information like the StackTrace or message:

```
e.ToString()
```

If you only want to catch a specific type of exception, you need to do something like:

```
try {
   // someCode
} catch (SpecificExceptionType e) {
   // someCode (e.g. Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); )
}
catch (AnotherSpecificExceptionType e) {
   // someCode (e.g. Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); )
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused - I thought the question was how to determine different types of exceptions. I pointed to 2 methods that provide this (and added e.GetType() in my last edit). What exactly am I missing? Don't want to sound rude, I just want to know how to do better in the future ;)

Comment: I also believe exception filtering answers the question